# Define uint8_t variable in Protocol Buffers message file

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to define a Point message in [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) which represents an RGB Colored Point in 3-dimensional space.

```
message Point {
    float x   = 1;
    float y   = 2;
    float z   = 3;
    uint8_t r = 4;
    uint8_t g = 5;
    uint8_t b = 6;
}
```

Here, `x, y, z` variables defines the position of Point and `r, g, b` defines the color in RGB space.

Since `uint8_t` is not defined in Protocol Buffers, I am looking for a workaround to define it. At present, I am using `uint32` in place of `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't anything in protobuf that represents a single byte - it simply isn't a thing that the wire-format worries about. The options are:

- varint (up to 64 bits input, up to 10 bytes on the wire depending on the highest set bit)
- fixed 32 bit
- fixed 64 bit
- length-prefixed (strings, sub-objects, packed arrays)
- (group tokens; a rare implementation detail)

A single byte isn't a good fit for *any* of those. Frankly, I'd use a single `fixed32` for all 3, and combine/decompose the 3 bytes manually (via shifting etc). The advantage here is that it would only have *one* field header for the 3 bytes, and wouldn't be artificially stretched via having high bits (I'm not sure that a composed RGB value is a good candidate for varint). You'd also have a spare byte if you want to add something else at a later date (alpha, maybe).

So:

```
message Point {
    float x     = 1;
    float y     = 2;
    float z     = 3;
    fixed32 rgb = 4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please add code snippet for combining rgb via shifting etc?

Comment: @RaviJoshi I don't know what language you're using :) I tend to favor C#, so: `obj.rgb = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;` and `byte r = (byte)(obj.rgb >> 16), g = (byte)(obj.rgb >> 8), b = (byte)obj.rgb;`.  If you're using C/C++, it should be fairly similar.

Comment: thanks a lot. Apologize to not mentioning language. I am using C++. Thank again for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is the correct approach. You should use the nearest data type capable of holding all values to be sent between the system. The source & destination systems should validate the data if it is in the correct range. For uint8_t this is int32 indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Some protocol buffers implementations actually allow this. In particular, [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) allows to either have .options file alongside the .proto file or use its extension directly in .proto file to fine tune interpretation of individual fields.

Specifying `int_size = IS_8` will convert `uint32` from message to `uint8_t` in generated structure.

```
import "nanopb.proto";

message Point {
    float x  = 1;
    float y  = 2;
    float z  = 3;
    uint32 r = 4 [(nanopb).int_size = IS_8];
    uint32 g = 5 [(nanopb).int_size = IS_8];
    uint32 b = 6 [(nanopb).int_size = IS_8];
}
```